# What is the reason that setDefaultUseCaches(false) of URLConnection is eagerly called in the org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener

Tags: api, memory-leaks, java

This question could be a bit difficult to find the answer. It's a questions in one series  with [What is the reason that Policy.getPolicy() is considered as it will retain a static reference to the context and can cause memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057421/why-policy-getpolicy-is-considered-as-it-will-retain-a-static-reference-to-the). You can read it so you may know more background.

Graped the source code from [`org.apache.cxf.common.logging.JDKBugHacks`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.cxf/cxf-common-utilities/2.3.1/org/apache/cxf/common/logging/JDKBugHacks.java) and also from [`org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.0/org/apache/catalina/core/JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener.java).

There is a piece of code. Here it is.

```
URL url = new URL("jar:file://dummy.jar!/"); 
URLConnection uConn = new URLConnection(url) {

    @Override
    public void connect() throws IOException{ 
        // NOOP
    }

};
uConn.setDefaultUseCaches(false);
```

The comment said

```
/*
 * Several components end up opening JarURLConnections without
 * first disabling caching. This effectively locks the file.
 * Whilst more noticeable and harder to ignore on Windows, it
 * affects all operating systems.
 * 
 * Those libraries/components known to trigger this issue
 * include:
 * - log4j versions 1.2.15 and earlier
 * - javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance()
 */
```

However I can hardly understand it. Why did they eagerly call `setDefaultUseCaches(false)` and why on Windows it's harmful that by default cache is true? I cannot find any clue in [`java.net.JarURLConnection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/JarURLConnection.java).

Comment: @Horstmann thanks for your kind remind. I find I have enough reputations to do this now. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I myself find an answer. Any one can correct me if you think I am wrong.
in [`sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/www/protocol/jar/JarURLConnection.java?av=h#JarURLConnection). I assume this is the default implementation of `java.net.JarURLConnection`. There is a piece of code below.

If cache is set to true, then it will not close the JarFile's connection. Which means it is locked.

```
class JarURLInputStream extends java.io.FilterInputStream {
        JarURLInputStream (InputStream src) {
            super (src);
        }
        public void close () throws IOException {
            try {
                super.close();
            } finally {
                if (!getUseCaches()) {
                    jarFile.close(); //will not close
                }
            }
        }
    }



    public void connect() throws IOException {
        if (!connected) {
            /* the factory call will do the security checks */
            jarFile = factory.get(getJarFileURL(), getUseCaches());

            /* we also ask the factory the permission that was required
             * to get the jarFile, and set it as our permission.
             */
            if (getUseCaches()) {
                jarFileURLConnection = factory.getConnection(jarFile);
            }

            if ((entryName != null)) {
                jarEntry = (JarEntry)jarFile.getEntry(entryName);
                if (jarEntry == null) {
                    try {
                        if (!getUseCaches()) {
                            jarFile.close();  //will not close
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("JAR entry " + entryName +
                                                    " not found in " +
                                                    jarFile.getName());
                }
            }
            connected = true;
        }
    }
```